# extjs dom.value

Tags: extjs

```
setValue : function(text) {
    Ext.get('id').dom.value = text;
    console.log(Ext.get('id').dom.value);
}
```

This piece of code sometimes stops working. My input is result of UI interaction. After setting the text several times value is not visually updated. console.log() always returns the correct result.

Any ideas how to visually refresh the element or what might cause the problem?

Answer (score 2):

DOM manipulation is not a good way, always try to solve issues in framework level.Try  like the following

`Ext.getComponet('id').setValue(text);`

Comment: You are correct this is the right way of doing this!!

Answer (score 1):

Ext.get is not recommended if you have a big form as it will have to got through all objects looking for your Id.

Instead you can user code like below

```
nameTextBox= new Ext.form.TextField({
                xtype: "textfield",
                fieldLabel: 'Name ',
                id: 'txtName',
                name: Name',
                allowBlank: false
            })
```

And then use your set function

```
setValue : function(text) { 
    nameTextBox.value = text; 
    console.log(nameTextBox.value); 
}
```

Comment: I can't do that as I only use ext.core package. I replaced Ext.get with document.getElementById and it fixes. Still I can't understand what is wrong with Ext.get though

Answer (score 1):

Ext.get('id').setValue('text');

[notes]
Ext.get() returns an Ext.Element, which has a set method for setting various attributes for a HTMLElement.